# Текст элемента на которую нажал

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста как получить текст элемента на которую нажал

Аналог: this.Text но это работает с формой

```
private void ЭЛЕМЕНТ_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = ЭЛЕМЕНТ.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void myHiro(object sender)
    {
        Label la = (Label) sender;
        string text  = la.Text;
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myHiro(sender);
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myHiro(sender);
    }
```

Думаю это самый лучший вариант к которому я мог прийти

Comment: Кажется понятно стало. Можно было один обработчик подписать на событие Click каждого контрола.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void txtBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;

    if(txt != null)
    {
      string text  = txt.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть возможность вынести это просто в войд ?

Comment: private void Name() { твой код } чтоб упростить и не писать в каждом длиный код

Comment: Я не разбираюсь честно в терминах но нужно чтоб написав это Name(); в элементе код работал также

Comment: @JazMartin - Думаю, вам подойдёт указание типа [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx), который является базовым для всех графических элементов, вместо `TextBox` и т. п.